# Query to create new fields based on the time span

Tags: mysql, sql

I am unable to write a query which needs the following :

I have 4 tables of Game products:

Table 1 (Soccer)

Product_Name

SoccerBall

SoccerShoes

SoccerShins

Table2 (Cricket)

Product_Name

CricketBall

CricketStumps

CricketBat

Table3(Rugby)

Product_Name

RugbyBall

Table4(Pingpong)

Product_Name

Pingpongball

I also have a table generating a revenue about all the products which is as follows:

Table5

Userid   OrderSno   Product_Name   OrderTime    Revenue

123        66243      CricketBall     12Jan2012        35

123        66553      CricketBat      15June2013       60

123        36476      SoccerBall      15Dec2013        15

The result table should be something like this :

Ordertime(Sorted)    Cricket(3months)  Cricket(6months) Cricket(Lifetime)

12Jan2012                     0                   0                0

15June2013                    0                   0                35

15 Dec2013                    0                  60                95 (60+35)

Soccer(3 months)    Soccer(6months)  Soccer(Lifetime)

```
      0                     0                 0

      0                     0                 0

      0                     0                 0
```

The above table gives the revenue generated for every product purchased before that particular product was purchased. This is based on the orderdate/time sorted.
For example : The first order placed by user 123 was on 12Jan2012. So that user had not purchased anything before that since it was his first order. Hence the first row of the result table should be 0.
Coming to the 2nd row, the 2nd purchase that he made was on 15June2013. SO the result table should contain all the revenue for the respective product type before 2nd order was made. Hence in this case 35 would be there under Cricket field (Since the Product_name belongs to Cricket table) and it would fall into the Lifetime field. This is because the order purchase date is 15June2013. So 3 months before this nothing was purchased. Similarly 6 months before this date nothing was purchased. But before 1 year or more than that Cricket Ball was purchased which generated a revenue of 35. Hence the value of 35 should fall into Lifetime field of Cricket based on the Product_Name of Cricket Ball.

The same thing should happen for all the products. I know the query is complex and i am not sure whether this is feasible or not. Since i am new to any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: SO you looking for like running totals ? Time1 = 3$, Time2 = 3$+4$ etc...?

Comment: Hi, yes somewhat similar. So based on the ordertime, i want the past revnue of that particular product.

Comment: If you are in a position to change your table design you really should because what you have now is a bad design. Splitting different products into different tables makes no sense really. What you should have is one product table where the game is an attribute; something like this _tableProducts(Product_Name, Game)_

Comment: Hi, yes i can create one single table and have the Product_Name and Game associated with it. So i can have 1 table from those 4 different tables. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if this exactly what you want but I think its work taking a look at. If you want all the sport in one table a Union would do it.

```
Select Product_Name
        ,YEAR(ordertime)
        ,SUM(case when MONTH(ordertime) in (1,2,3) then revenue else 0 end) 'Q1'
        ,SUM(case when MONTH(ordertime) between 1 and 6 then revenue else 0 end) 'Q2'
        ,SUM(case when MONTH(ordertime) between 1 and 9 then revenue else 0 end) 'Q3'
        ,SUM(revenue) 'Q4'
from PingPong
group by Product_Name, YEAR(ordertime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But i am not sure how it would take the product_name from Table 5 and figure it out that it should fall into the time span fields of that particular sport. For example: 2nd row to Table 5, the Product_Name is  CricketBat. Hence that means the result table should generate the revenue figures of the previous order of CricketBat. Now previous order is of CricketBall which falls under "Cricket" table. Hence the revenue should field of the Cricket time spans should be changed and others should be zero.

Comment: So for every ordertime/date, it should check all its previous orders and then fill up the revenue fields. So if the 1st and 2nd rows are for Cricket Product, 3rd row is for Soccer product and 4th row again is for Cricket, then for the 4th row : it should be able to generate a result table giving the revenues of 1st, 2nd and 3rd row. So it should have revenues for both Cricket and Soccer filled up.

Comment: Right that is what the group by will do for you. It will group all the same products, You might need the Year portion if you are only handling 1 year.  this answer would work for 1 table, since you need to do it for each table you just need to change the table it is looking at. I assume the Cricket Table cannot have PingPong sales? Then do a Union to combine all the table ... another option would be to create a Temporary table insert all the records and do a single Select from that, depending on data size this could be slower or faster